Generator of the middle cohomology of a smooth quadric hypersurface
Let $X \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ be a smooth hypersurface of degree $d$. I know that its cohomology groups are
$$\begin{align}
H^{2k+1}(X) &= 0 && \text{ for all } k \in \mathbb{Z}, \\
H^{2k}(X) &= \mathbb{Z}\langle h^k \rangle && \text{ for } 0 \leq 2k < n-1, \\
H^{2k}(X) &= \mathbb{Z}\langle \tfrac{1}{d} h^k \rangle && \text{ for } n-1 < 2k \leq 2(n-1).
\end{align}$$
Here $h$ denotes the restriction to $X$ of the hyperplane class in $H^2(\mathbb{P}^n)$. I am trying to finish the computation for degree $d = 2$, and I know from this post that in this case $H^{n-1}(X)$ is zero if $n-1$ is odd and free of rank 1 if $n-1$ is even. The last step is therefore to know who the generator $g \in H^{n-1}(X)$ is. The Lefschetz hyperplane theorem tells us that $H^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^n)$ injects into $H^{n-1}(X)$, so $h^{(n-1)/2} = ag$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, and all we have to do is to compute $a$.
But now,
$$h^{n-1} = (h^{(n-1)/2})^2 = (ag)^2 = a^2 g^2 = a^2 \tfrac{1}{2} h^{n-1}$$
because $g^2$ is a generator of $H^{2n-2}(X)$ by Poincaré duality. Hence I arrive at $a^2 = 2$ which makes no sense. Where did I go wrong? What is the actual generator of $H^{n-1}(X)$?

Your statement “I know that…“ is incorrect.

I think you misread the linked post. The relevant part is "So far all we know is that $H^{n-1}(\mathbb{CP}^n)$ injects into it; this is $\mathbb{Z}$ if n is odd but $0$ if $n$ is even." The last part describes $H^{n-1}(\mathbb{CP}^n)$, not $H^{n-1}(X)$. In fact, $H^{n-1}(X)$ might be of rank 2 (with $n=3$, you get a quadric which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ and so $H^2(X)$ is of rank 2).

@Roland you are right, somehow I got the $d=1$ and $d=2$ cases mixed. The true statement is that $H^{n-1}(X)$ is free of rank 2. Thanks!
